# I am having errors while getting octomap from rgbdslam_v2 GUI and also where do I get the output of online octomapping?

Tags: slam, navigation, octomap, 3d-slam, rgbdslam-v2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As it is essential to get octomap for navigation and path planning but I am not able to do that I have followed the answer also but it isnt helping.
https://answers.ros.org/question/9712/how-to-use-rgbd-6d-slam-for-path-planning-and-navigation-with-kinect/

There is also error while opening pcd files from the rgbdslam_v2 GUI.
The error of opening of pcd file is this:

> [ERROR] [1506803049.883978384]: Cloud has "flat" dimensions: 1 x 14585991

I am using roslaunch rgbdslam rgbdslam.launch

and then play my rosbag file and the GUI is building 3D map but not octomap. Once the process is over I try to save the octomap but the only output I am getting is this(this is map.ot file generated from save octomap):

## Octomap OcTree file

## (feel free to add / change comments, but leave the first line as it is!)

id ColorOcTree
size 0
res 0.05
data

I am noob at slam but I know bit of ros I have gone through every answer on the ros answers but it isnt helping me can anyone help me with this I would be pleased and can you tell me how to view octomap i have installed octavis.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271984/i-am-having-errors-while-getting-octomap-from-rgbdslam_v2-gui-and-also-where-do-i-get-the-output-of-online-octomapping?/) by [Dhagash Desai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26869/dhagash-desai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://answers.ros.org/question/253630/empty-octomap-in-rgbdslam/

Please use this answer to solve the problem its a sure fix for the problem.
Anyone know how to open a .ot file from save octomap.

---

Originally posted by [Dhagash Desai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26869/dhagash-desai/) with karma: 16 on 2017-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0